# convexity of $f(x)+f(g(x))$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, inequality, convex-analysis

suppose $f$ is a convex function. i.e.,

for all $0\leq\lambda\leq 1$:
\begin{equation}
f(\lambda x+(1-\lambda)y)\leq \lambda f(x)+(1-\lambda)f(y)
\end{equation}
Consider the following function:
\begin{equation}
h(x)=f(x)+f(g(x))
\end{equation}
what can we say about convexity of **$h$ w.r.t $x$**?

more specifically, under what condition $h$ is a convex function as well? i.e.,
\begin{equation}
h(\lambda x+(1-\lambda y))\leq \lambda h(x)+(1-\lambda)h(y)
\end{equation}

note that there is no restriction on the convexity of $g$.

Comment: What kind of conditions are you thinking of? – A simple case would be $f(x) = x$, so hat $h(x) = x + g(x)$ which is convex iff $g$ is convex. I doubt that anything can be said without restrictions on $g$.

Comment: like for instance, if I allow g to be restricted, can we find all the family of functions like g that leads to the convexity of h?

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: Also, can we make restrictions on $f$, or only on $g$?

Comment: @supinf It's a general question, so if you have some idea to restrict f which results in the convexity of h, I would appreciate it if you could share it.

Answer (score 2):

If $g: \Bbb R \to \Bbb R$ is a *linear* function then $h(x) = f(x) + f(g(x))$ is convex for any convex function $f: \Bbb R \to \Bbb R$.

Conversely, linear functions are the only functions $g$ with that property:

- Choosing the convex function $f(x) = x$ implies that $h(x) = x + g(x)$ is convex, so $g$ must be convex.
- Choosing the convex function $f(x) = -x$ implies that $h(x) = -x - g(x)$ is convex, so $g$ must be concave.

A function which is both convex and concave is necessarily linear.